# Efficient way to interact with database on server from Android

Tags: android, node.js, database, client-server, soa

I have a server running on node js+MySQL and an Android client.I want to get data from database on server side  from android .I have two choices:

1st Way:Connect to server using URL and pass whole query as parameter to server.Server then extracts parameter and passes it to MySQL as it is.

Suppose i want to get notices from database then I will call the following url:

```
http://my-server/?data=Select * from notice where noticeId>12
```

The server will get the *'data'* parameter and passes it to database without analyzing it anyway and returns the output(It can be error or valid result.To analyze , it is job of client).

By this way I am worried about that my queries can be visible to anyone who will be able decompile apk and It will be very simple to gain control over my database, which is security concern for me.

2nd Way:Write all the database queries on server and request a particular result from android ,identified by a Key as follows

On Android

```
http://my-server/?data=QWEDCVBNMHGFD
```

On server

```
if (data==QWEDCVBNMHGFD)
{
  .......
result=calldatabase("select * from notice where noticeId>12");
  .....
 return finalresult;
}
```

The problem in this approach is that I have approx 20 queries and I don't think it will be right way to always keep comparing keys(still not sure :D).

Is there any other way of interacting with database and keeping the communication secure?

Comment: what about creating REST API ?

Comment: Thanks for help Jozef.I haven't studied much about them.Will let you know  if it solved my problem.